# How can i sign a message using my private key and later recover my account address from that signature to validate my account?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, private-key

I am using ganache blockchain, I want to verify that this is the key of a specific address.

> Address : 0x24Ff3B7cacCcd9D05353dFB0Ff5b22062A13FbE0
>   Key : c28b71d6d57239ae0a575c5f5f4e7837092238c73eaaaa5e2b5e01c42714a1ed

I want to recover my address using this key to check that the key belongs to that particular address.

Comment: Question is not clear, You want to do it with web3 only or you are also using contract in the process.

Comment: You can't get a private key from a signature! Public address is built from the private key, so to find it you would have to find the private key first. Also what do you mean by validating your account? What do you try to achieve in the end?

Comment: i want to use my private key as an password whose username is account or public key

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to locally check if the public address belongs to the private key is to use nodejs and ethereumjs-wallet.

```
var ethjsWallet = require("ethereumjs-wallet");
var wallet = ethjsWallet.fromPrivateKey(yourPrivateKey)
var address = wallet.getAddress()
```

If you want to recover the public address from a signature, then you can use something like ethereumjs-utils. With `ecrecover`, you can recover the public key and from there on you can convert the public key to the public address.

Comment: i used your implementation                                                                                     var bufStr="c28b71d6d57239ae0a575c5f5f4e7837092238c73eaaaa5e2b5e01c42714a1ed";

var buf = Buffer.from(bufStr, 'utf8');
console.log(buf);
var ethjsWallet = require("ethereumjs-wallet");
var wallet = ethjsWallet.fromPrivateKey(buf)
var address = wallet.getAddress()

Comment: and got error : srajan@srajan-virtual-machine ~ $ node test.js
<Buffer 63 32 38 62 37 31 64 36 64 35 37 32 33 39 61 65 30 61 35 37 35 63 35 66 35 66 34 65 37 38 33 37 30 39 32 32 33 38 63 37 33 65 61 61 61 61 35 65 32 62 ... >
/home/srajan/node_modules/ethereumjs-wallet/index.js:23
    throw new Error('Private key does not satisfy the curve requirements (ie. it is invalid)')